# Power series infinity at every point of boundary

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Is there an example of a power series $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ with radius of convergence $0<R<\infty$ so that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kw^k=\infty$ for all $w$ with $|w|=R$

Thank you kindly.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kw^k=\infty$  ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a power series $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ with radius of convergence $0<R<\infty$.
Assume $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n=\infty$ for all $z$ with $|z|=R$.
There are at most finitely many zeroes $z_1,\ldots,z_m$ of $f$ in the open disk $D=\{z\colon|z|<R\}$ so that for a suitable polynomial $p$  we obtain a function $g\colon D\to\mathbb C$, $g(z)=\frac{p(z)}{f(z)}$ that is holomorphic on $D$ and $g(z)\to0$ (why?) as $|z|\to 1$, hence is bounded. Using the reflection principle we get an entire bounded function, hence $g$ is constant.
But then the power series of $f$ is better-behaved on $\partial D$, contradiction.

Comment: Why are there only finitely many zeros of $f$ in $D$ ?

Comment: And even if that were true I don't see why $g$ would tend to $0$ as $|z|\to 1$. Your question "why?" is a very good one, indeed.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : Note also that it is even impossible to have $|f(z)| \rightarrow \infty$ on a set of positive measure, by the Luzin-Privalov Theorem applied to $1/f$...

Comment: Also, how do you deduce that $|f(z)| \rightarrow \infty$ as $|z| \rightarrow 1$, from the hypothesis that $\sum a_n z^n =\infty$ for all $z \in \partial D$? I only see how to deduce that $|f(z)|$ has **nontangential** limit $\infty$ on $\partial D$, by Abel's Theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1):

No there is not. In fact, there is no example of such power series $\sum_n a_n z^n$ such that $\sum_n a_n w^n = \infty$ for all $w$ in a set of positive measure in $\partial D$, where $D=\{|z|<R\}$. Indeed, suppose there exists such a power series $f$. By [Abel's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem), we deduce that $f(z)$ has non-tangential boundary values $\infty$ on a set of positive measure in $\partial D$. This means that $1/f$ is a meromorphic function in $D$ with non-tangential boundary values $0$ on a set of positive measure in $\partial D$, and so $1/f$ is identically zero in $D$, by the [Luzin-Privalov Theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Luzin-Privalov_theorems). So $f \equiv \infty$ in $D$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

For the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{z^n}$ radius  of convergence  $R=1$, but it diverges $\forall{z}\colon \;\;|z|=1.$

Comment: he didn't say it shall diverge but to be infty

Answer (score 0):

Take the series $\sum_k z^k$. its radius of convergence $R=1$ and for $z=e^{i\theta}$
the series $\sum_n e^{in\theta}$ diverges since the term $e^{in\theta}$ does not converge to $0$

Comment: See above, the question did not ask for divergence, but for divergence to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

The series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \cdot z^k $$ has convergence radius $1$ and for $z=1$ the absolut value of the series goes to infty.

Comment: Hm, that's just $z+z^2+z^4$. And if youmean $4|k$, this is the series for $4\ln(z^4)=16\ln(z)$ instead of $\ln z$, so I don't see essentially different behaviour.

Comment: oh right, i think there is none which goes always to infty